# How do French feel about calling binary digits 'bits'?

Tags: nombres

I'd like to get the reference [here](https://youtu.be/bdMfjfT0lKk?t=3m32s).

He mentions that calling ternary digits 'trits' might feel strange to an English speaker, but to French speakers, even shortening binary digits to 'bits', which is of course pretty common, might feel just as strange.

I haven't found any other translation for bit or bits from French to English, so what does he mean with his statement?

Comment: Perhaps you should look under "bite".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds exactly like "*bite*" (dick). So of course most student laugh a little when they start learning about it and hearing it from teachers, they make a few jokes about it etc. After a while it passes, it's not that funny after you hear it 200 times a day.

As someone studying computer science, the class can still have to hold their laughter if a teacher says something like "*il prend 32 bits en même temps*"...

Comment: Oeuf corse, it's trou. :)